# Javascript convert dates

Tags: javascript, php, date

I am getting this `"20131218"`  date/time value from an API result.

What I want to do is convert this date into something like this `"2013-12-18"`. I know this is very easy in PHP by simply doing this code:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('20131218'));
```

output: `2013-12-18`

This is what I tried in javascript:

```
var myDate = new Date("20131218");
console.log(myDate);
```

But the output is `Date{ Invalid Date }` so obviously this is wrong.

My question here what is the equivalent of strtotime in javascript? or if there's no equivalent, how would I convert this value as my expected result(`2013-12-18`) using javascript?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Check out http://momentjs.com

Answer (score 1):

The value is invalid to convert it to date. So either from your PHP code send it as a proper format like `20131218`

Or convert the value you get in your Javascript to similar kind of format.

```
var dateVal="20131218"; 
/*
 // If it's number  *******   //
var numdate=20131218;
var dateVal=numdate.toString();
*/

var year=dateVal.substring(0,4);
var mnth=dateVal.substring(4,6);
var day=dateVal.substring(6,8);
var dateString=year+"-"+mnth+"-"+day;


var actualDate = new Date(dateString); 
alert(actualDate);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8E7g5/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a [Date.parse](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) method but the string you have is not suitable to pass to it. You don't really need to create a date object just to format a string. Consider:

```
function formatDateStr(s) {
    s = s.match(/\d\d/g);
    return s[0] + s[1] + '-' + s[2] + '-' + s[3];
}

alert(formatDateStr('20131218')); // '2013-12-18'
```

If you wish to convert it to a date object, then:

```
function parseDateStr(s) {
    s = s.match(/\d\d/g);
    return new Date(s[0] + s[1], --s[2], s[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is showing Invalid date is, it wants it to be in format

```
Following format: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

If you breakdown your string using following format just add dash at relevant places then you are good to go and use newDate.

```
1.    var myDate = new Date("2013-12-18"); 
      alert(myDate);

2.    var myDate = new Date(2013,12,18);
```

Eventually you can modify your string manipulate it and use it in aforementioned format.